# Why does `each` not iterate over jQuery objects?

Tags: jquery, iteration

The jQuery `each` method iterating over a jQuery selector:

```
$('.foo').each(function(){
  ...this...
});

$.each($('.foo'), function(index, object){
  ...object...
});
```

seems to assign a plain JavaScript object to the `this` keyword in the first example above and `object` variable in the second.

My impression of jQuery is that it makes chaining of methods easy by returning jQuery objects and not plain JavaScript objects, whenever returning some object that represents a DOM. But here, it looks like I cannot just use `this` or `object` as jQuery object and do:

```
this.text('color', 'red')

object.css('color', 'red')
```

but I have to turn them into jQuery objects:

```
$(this).text('color', 'red')

$(object).css('color', 'red')
```

Is my understanding correct? Why is this the case? I would like to know the logic behind this design decision.

Comment: Consistency, I'd think - with jQuery, `this` *always* refers to a plain element (or something like it) and never to a jQuery object. If you had to check which method you're using before knowing whether you need to use `this` or `$(this)`, it would be a tiny bit more cognitive overhead... I guess.

Comment: Note that this is the same way pretty much everything else works in jQuery, e.g. event listeners, functions passed to `text`/`css`/etc.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think that is the case. If I have `$.fn.foo = function(){...};`, and call `$('.bar').foo()`, then within the method body of `foo()`, `this` **is** a jQuery object.

Comment: @Ry- But event listeners or functions do not need to be wrapped as jQuery objects. They are useful as is, and are used as is in jQuery.

Comment: @sawa: I’m talking about `this` in event listeners attached via jQuery and the function-parameter overloads to methods like `$.fn.text`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for linking to the duplicate question. It looks like the answer is performance.